# Sqlalchemy nested class hierarchy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, entity-attribute-value

While working with Relationships with Joined Inheritance in sqlalchemy, I have a complex class hierarchies as you can see in this model, derived from the following schema: [Entity Attribute Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNI8l.png) and this following complex diagram : [Entities and Classifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GaiX.png).

Is this model correct? where do i add the relationship to these models? how do i rewrite this model?

```
class Party(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'party'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'party',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }

class Organisation(Party):
    __tablename__ = 'organisation'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('party.id'), primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(50))
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey('party.id'))
    company = relationship("Company", back_populates="managers")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'organisation',
    'polymorphic_on':type
    }

class Legal():
    __tablename__ = 'legal' 
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('organisation.id'), primary_key=True)   
    name = Column(String(50))
    tax_id = Column(String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'legal',
    }

class Informal():
    __tablename__ = 'informal'  
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('organisation.id'), primary_key=True)   
    name = Column(String(50))
    tax_id = Column(String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'informal',
    }



class Person(Party):
    __tablename__ = 'party'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('party.id'), primary_key=True)
    engineer_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'person',
    }
```

Comment: Don't duplicate the `type` column and `'polymorphic_on'` in `Organisation`.

Comment: thanks for your remark, but from the posted diagram, it appears there will be lot of duplications. what do you suggest?

Comment: To be honest, I'd suggest you get back to the drawing board. The model you've presented does not seem to reflect the diagrams and would seem to contain multiple issues. Should `Legal` and `Informal` inherit from `Organisation`? Your question is a bit unclear and very broad.

Comment: That's where i have got confused a bit but i believe this is what happens, `legal` and `Informal` are distinct entities inheriting from `Organisation` and Inside `Legal` there is distinct attributes i.e `Tax ID Number`

Comment: @IljaEverilä what do you suggest?